# c# app communicate with vb6 app

Tags: c#-4.0, vb6, ipc, winsock

I wrote a c#.net 4.0 application and I need to send data to a VB6 application.
the VB6 can send and recive data via DDE, but I can't find any working and or understandable DDE protocol for my C# app. I can try and change the communication protocol of the VB app.
Do you have any suggestions for suitable protocol?

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661003/best-ipc-for-vb6-and-net-application) and I think I will choose the TCP winsock protocol, which is availible at the two workspaces, but I can't find any working code sample of such multilanguege use of Winsock.
I'll be glad to get such example.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not remember... It was ages ago...
I think I just threw it away and communicated with Files IO on shared folder. Not too efficient but it did the Job.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with DDE you could check out this project:  http://ndde.codeplex.com/
or http://www.angelfire.com/biz/rhaminisys/ddeinfo.html.  I have no experience using them, but they aim to solve the problem.

However, if you have the source code for the VB6 application, then it may be much simpler for you to expose a COM interface.

You can do so by changing the project from Standard EXE to ActiveX EXE and creating at least one public class exposing your methods.  I did this for all my VB6 apps that previously used DDE and higly reccommend it. It gives the client application a better interface to work with.

Comment: The problem with the VB6 app is that I'm have authorities for changing it. this is a third party app. I can only suggest changes for Compatibility. What you suggest is too much for asking.

Comment: But, I'll check the DDE issue again.

Comment: +1 Another option for DDE would be to write a VB6 tool to send/receive the DDE for you. Make it an ActiveX exe and then you would be able to call it from .Net